# Как правильно добавить заголовок для WinHttp.WinHttpRequest.5.1 vba excel?

Tags: excel, vba, visual-basic, web-scraping, parse

Я хочу спарсить в excel сайт закупок, но при запросе отображается другая страница(не как в браузере), как будто она не существует. В питоне это вылечилось через добавление user agent. В ВБА тоже нашёл такой метод, но он не работает, скорее всего что-то не правильно делаю. Помогите пожалуйста!

```
Function GetHTTPResponse() As String
   On Error Resume Next
   Set oXMLHTTP = CreateObject("WinHttp.WinHttpRequest.5.1")
   object_poiska = "Парацетамол"
   sURL = "https://zakupki.gov.ru/epz/contract/search/results.html?searchString=" & object_poiska & "&morphology=on&search-filter=%D0%94%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B5+%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B7%D0%BC%D0%B5%D1%89%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F&fz44=on&contractStageList_0=on&contractStageList_1=on&contractStageList_2=on&contractStageList_3=on&contractStageList=0%2C1%2C2%2C3&contractCurrencyID=-1&budgetLevelsIdNameHidden=%7B%7D&sortBy=UPDATE_DATE&pageNumber=1&sortDirection=false&recordsPerPage=_10&showLotsInfoHidden=false"
    With oXMLHTTP
        .Open "GET", sURL, False
        .setRequestHeader "User-Agent", "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/51.0.2704.103 Safari/537.36"
        .send
        GetHTTPResponse = .responseText
    End With
    Set oXMLHTTP = Nothing
End Function
```

Comment: Переведи на русский.

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.